# Applications disappear from notification area over time

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, notification-area

I've added Slack to the notification area of the taskbar by going to Settings and finding `Select which icons appear on the taskbar` section.  I switched Slack on on and all was good.

Eventually, after a month or two, Slack disappears.  I go back into `Select which icons appear on the taskbar` section and sure enough, Slack is set to off.

I suspect that's because Slack keeps updating itself and the EXE itself is changing.  But that's just a guess.

What can I do to fix this problem?

P.S. Clarification. Windows 10 doesn't have "Only Show Notifications" - that's Windows 8.x.  It's either on or off.  As in image below:

[image]

Comment: *Slack is set to off.* Is that what its new setting says? Or is it "Only show notifications?" (or something else?)

Comment: @Twisty I updated the question regarding the setting to address your question.  Plus image.

Comment: Helpful! I mistakenly looked at a Server 2012 R2 machine for reference, forgetting that doesn't have feature parity with Win 10.

Comment: I really want to know this too. Its frustrating.

Comment: @O'Rooney Oh, I totally forgot to update the question.  I suspected that they were not setting AppID in their installer (because I had a similar issue in my windows app years ago). Without it, Windows can't tell that a previous install is connected to the new install. Therefore, it would remove it from the notification list.  I actually contacted their tech support and that in fact is the issue.  It's on their "to do" list.

Comment: Yeah, I got the same reply.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I contacted Slack support and they said:

> Unfortunately this is a really annoying bug we have in the desktop app. When a new update is installed, it's placed in its own subdirectory within the Slack folder inside your %localappdata% folder.
>
> From that, Windows picks this new version up as a new application and returns it back to the hidden area of your tray. This is something we're hoping to have fixed in a future release by adjusting our updates. Sadly, I don't have an ETA on when that change may occur

Comment: Is your support question in a bugtracker somewhere? Would be helpfull if everybody visiting this topic to upvote it. It's really fucking with my workflow system.

Comment: I don’t think so. I no longer have access to the slack account sorry (forced to use Teams, argh)